# Can I log PIC time without a valid medical?

Tags: faa-regulations, general-aviation, pilots, medical, logging

Here is the scenario. Could you please tell me if
this pilot can log PIC time?

I am a private pilot and my medical is expired.
I want to fly so I am trying to fly with another private pilot friend.
My friend has a valid medical and flight review.
The flight will be VFR, in VFR conditions.

I am going to fly so I will be the sole manipulator. Can I do so without a medical? Can my friend be acting PIC, with just me flying and logging PIC?
My friend is going to watch me.

Comment: What is preventing you from going an getting a medical or going through the BasicMed process?

Comment: @SMSvonderTann Seems like rather private information to me.

Comment: Also irrelevant to the question, since the reasons have nothing to do with improving the questions or how we would frame an answer.

Answer (score 1):

No. You need to dig into the regulations a bit to get at the answer:

§ 61.51(e):

> Logging pilot-in-command flight time.
>
> > (1) A sport, recreational, private, commercial, or airline transport pilot may log pilot in command flight time for flights-
> >
> > > (i) Except when logging flight time under § 61.159(c), when the pilot is the sole manipulator of the controls of an aircraft for which the pilot is rated, or has sport pilot privileges for that category and class of aircraft, if the aircraft class rating is appropriate;

This seems to imply you can at first glance, but you need to dig into the definitions of the terms used. § 1.1 defines "flight time":

> Pilot time that commences when an aircraft moves under its own power for the purpose of flight and ends when the aircraft comes to rest after landing

and then § 61.1 defines "pilot time":

> Pilot time means that time in which a person -
>
> (i) Serves as a required pilot flight crewmember;
>
> (ii) Receives training from an authorized instructor in an aircraft, full flight simulator, flight training device, or aviation training device;
>
> (iii) Gives training as an authorized instructor in an aircraft, full flight simulator, flight training device, or aviation training device; or
>
> (iv) Serves as second in command in operations conducted in accordance with § 135.99(c) of this chapter when a second pilot is not required under the type certification of the aircraft or the regulations under which the flight is being conducted, provided the requirements in § 61.159(c) are satisfied.

The only one here that could possibly apply to you, assuming your friend is not a CFI, is the first. However, you cannot serve as a required flight crewmember without a medical, as stated in § 61.3(c)(1):

> A person may serve as a required pilot flight crewmember of an aircraft only if that person holds the appropriate medical certificate issued under part 67 of this chapter, or other documentation acceptable to the FAA, that is in that person's physical possession or readily accessible in the aircraft. Paragraph (c)(2) of this section provides certain exceptions to the requirement to hold a medical certificate.

unless one of the exceptions in § 61.3(c)(2) applies to you.

In short, you can only log "flight time," which is a type of "pilot time," which only accrues if you are a "required flight crewmember." Since you are not allowed to be a required flight crewmember without a medical, you can't log time either.

You *can* log PIC time if you are receiving training from a CFI in a plane you are rated for. If your medical has lapsed and you don't have a medical condition that makes flying unsafe, picking up some training from a CFI is a safe and legal way to continue flying and logging time while you work on getting your medical in order.

Comment: Um... there are plenty of times that rated pilots swap controls, operate as "sole manipulator", yet are not both required crewmembers.  Does that time not count?

Comment: @MichaelHall Good question. I feel like it should, but I can't find a strong citation that it is the case. I suppose one could argue that the pilot flying (at any given moment) is the *only* required crewmember? Which would mean whoever is flying could log, but the pilot not flying cannot.

Comment: From the [Grau interpretation](https://faa.gov/about/office_org/headquarters_offices/agc/practice_areas/regulations/interpretations/Data/interps/2010/Grau-Embry-Riddle%20Aeronautical%20University_2010_Legal_Interpretation.pdf), "For purposes of this provision, a required pilot flight crewmember means a pilot assigned to
perform a duty in an aircraft during flight time." Perhaps they *both* count as required crewmembers? The PNF still can't log PIC time in that case since 61.51(e)(1)(iii) specifies that the additional pilot must be required by regulation or type certification.

Comment: It is an interesting interpretation.  I can see your logic.

Comment: I would stop at 61.51(e) and answer yes.  If you try hard enough you can talk yourself out of almost anything.

Comment: @MichaelHall Indeed, under the definition of a required crewmember meaning "a pilot assigned to perform a duty in an aircraft during flight time," swapping controls (i.e. *assigning* a pilot to perform the *duty* of flying the airplane) would indeed change who is a required crewmember and so who could log. I think it makes sense to draw a distinction between assigning a rated, current, and legal pilot to fly versus allowing a passenger (whether a pilot or not) to manipulate the controls under supervision. Even if a passenger is a pilot, if they aren't current or otherwise legal [...]

Comment: [continued] I don't think assigning them the duty of flying is in any way legal.

Comment: *"Even if a passenger is a pilot, if they aren't current or otherwise legal I don't think assigning them the duty of flying is in any way legal."*  The CFRs make no mention of "assigning them the duty of flying".  They distinguish between acting as PIC and sole manipulator.  I agree that someone acting as PIC cannot assign acting PIC duty to someone not medically current.  But they can let a rated pilot, (even a non pilot!) manipulate the controls.

Comment: And the regs clearly say that you can log it in "*an aircraft for which the pilot is rated*" without imposing an additional restriction that the medical certificate be current.

Comment: @MichaelHall As I said in my comment on your post, I don't think you can interpret 14 CFR § 61.51(e) without the definition of the term "flight time," which clearly requires a pilot to be a "required pilot flight crewmember" (i.e. be *assigned a duty*, according to the Grau interpretation. In any case one is not a "flight crewmember," required or otherwise, unless assigned a duty), or to be receiving/giving training, or to be serving as SIC under certain part 135 operations. The pilot needing to be rated is an *additional* requirement over the time counting as "flight time" in the first place.

Comment: Where did you find that definition of "pilot time"?  I don't see it alphabetically in 1.1.

Comment: @MichaelHall It's in 61.1.

Comment: While I can follow how you arrived at your conclusion, I think we need to agree to disagree on this one.  Thorough knowledge of the FARs is expected of pilots, but there is also a reasonable expectation that in any regulation the key points be included within the applicable section.  As I mentioned somewhat flippantly before, I could probably dig deep enough to find a way to disallow any number things by omission or linking to a requirement listed in some different section and context.  Anyway, time for me to move on with my weekend...

Comment: FWIW, the AOPA has written an article regarding the logging of pilot-in-command time.  I've linked it [HERE](https://www.aopa.org/training-and-safety/learn-to-fly/old-pages/legacy-pages/aviation-subject-report-logging-pilot-in-command-pic-time). Note  Scenario 1 of the article agrees with Michael's answer.  I'm not saying that this supersedes @Chris-RegenerateResponse position, just that it is probably worth a look.

Comment: @MichaelHall Certainly reasonable people can disagree on regulation! Otherwise we wouldn't have lawyers. I'm also now imagining how unimpressed an NTSB investigator would be if there was an accident, and they checked my logbook to find I had been logging PIC time without a valid medical. Since the other pilot isn't logging time, it seems they only would have my word that I wasn't also acting as PIC. Anyway I hope you have a nice weekend :)

Comment: @757toga Interesting. I felt their analysis is wrong for another reason- it relies on 61.51(e)(1)(iii), which states that it only applies when the regulations require two or more pilots. And if the regulations *require* two pilots, I really don't see how it could possibly be legal for pilot A to be one of the *required* pilots without a medical.

Comment: Regarding the hypothetical NTSB investigation, the first question any investigator will ask is "who is the PIC?"  To which your friend will be obligated to raise his/her hand.  Second question will be "who was flying?", but it will be your friend in the hot seat first...

Comment: I have a current CFI, but no medical certificate. I am allowed to conduct flight instruction and log it under FAR 61.51(e)(3) as pilot-in-command flight time as long as the person I'm instructing is qualified and acts as PIC.  This is a similar, but not exactly the same, principle involved as the discussion and different viewpoints  surrounding this question. @MichaelHall

Comment: @757toga Yes, that is *specifically* set out as allowed under the definition of "pilot time."

Comment: I agree with you (I upvoted your answer).  That's why I only said the issue/discussion was similar in *principle* (no medical, but logging pilot-in-command time).  As you have pointed out, the definition of "pilot time" in 61.1 speaks for itself.

Answer (score 0):

It is pretty simple. If your medical is not valid, you can not be pilot in command.

You can go flying with your friend, but he will be pilot in command, and he will log the time.

Comment: I agree you cannot act as PIC without a current medical, but sole manipulator?

Comment: I keep forgetting about FAA “sole manipulator” since I am not FAA licenced. My guess is no to “sole manipulator” since his medical is not valid and he is not receiving training.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

Regarding logging PIC time, 14 CFR § 61.51(e) states in part:

> (1) A sport, recreational, private, commercial, or airline transport
> pilot may log pilot in command flight time for flights-
>
> (i) Except when logging flight time under § 61.159(c), **when the pilot
> is the sole manipulator of the controls of an aircraft for which the
> pilot is rated**, or has sport pilot privileges for that category and
> class of aircraft, if the aircraft class rating is appropriate;
>
> (ii) When the pilot is the sole occupant in the aircraft;
>
> (iii) When the pilot, except for a holder of a sport or recreational
> pilot certificate, acts as pilot in command of an aircraft for which
> more than one pilot is required under the type certification of the
> aircraft or the regulations under which the flight is conducted; or

You really don't need to go any further than that.

You cannot "perform the duties" or "act as PIC" without a current medical certificate, which is stated clearly in 61.23(a)(3)(ii).  The FAA breaks PIC duties out separately from "sole manipulator" and your friend must be act as PIC.  However, if you are a rated pilot flying the airplane you can log the time while you are sole manipulator per 61.51(e)(i).

Comment: Seems like poor legal advice to suggest one doesn't need to check the definitions of terms used, when "flight time" and "pilot time" are both clearly defined in the regs. I'd be open to an argument that my analysis is in some way flawed, but just ignoring the definitions seems rather cavalier.

Comment: @Chris-RegenerateResponse, I am not offering legal advice, and I'm not ignoring definitions, this one just happens to be self contained.  In this context, PIC time is defined as "*when the pilot is the sole manipulator of the controls of an aircraft for which the pilot is rated*".  If a medical certificate was also required it would say that just like it does when describing requirements for "acting as PIC" in 61.23(a)(3)(ii).  It is well established that acting as PIC and logging PIC as sole manipulator are distinctly different.

Comment: ...and I am no more cavalier for seeking a permissive interpretation than you are irrational for seeking the most restrictive one.  You are free to disagree, and I always welcome constructive feedback, but I'm not alone here.  Let the votes be cast...

Comment: Just stating my thoughts. The full sentence (chopping off the irrelevant parts that apply only to sport pilots and part 135 operators) is "A sport, recreational, private, commercial, or airline transport pilot may log pilot in command **flight time** for flights when the pilot is the sole manipulator of the controls of an aircraft for which the pilot is rated." I don't think that you can interpret this sentence without reference to the definition of "flight time." But as far as I can tell there is no FAA interpretation directly dealing with this, so we can agree to disagree.

Comment: FWIW, the AOPA has written an article regarding the logging of pilot-in-command time. I've linked it [HERE](https://www.aopa.org/training-and-safety/learn-to-fly/old-pages/legacy-pages/aviation-subject-report-logging-pilot-in-command-pic-time). Note Scenario 1 of the article agrees with your answer. I'm not saying that this supersedes @Chris-RegenerateResponse position, just that it is probably worth a look